# SQL - Variable formule to calculate prices

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in need of the correct code syntax that calculates the price after discount for the following 4 scenarios. Please note that I'm looking for a variable solution as the amount of commas in the discount column can be more tha 3 as well.

I have a table dwh.FactTurnover.

**One of the columns is the SalesPriceExcl (excl discounts)

**One of the columns is "discount" which can contain the following:**

Sample data:

[image]

- Example : 10 (this is a discount of 10%)
- Example 2: 58,12 (this is a discount of 58% followed by an additional discount of 12%)
- Example 3: 50,10,15 (this is a discount of 50% followed by a discount of 10% followed by a discount of 15%)
- Example 4: P --> blocked, no discount possible

**This should give the following solutions for the above examples:**

- Example 1: 100$ * 0.90 = 90$
- Example 2: 39.5877$ * 0.42 * 0.88 = 14.63$
- Example 3: 100$ * 0.50 * 0.90 * 0.85 = 38.25$
- Example 4: 100$ * P = 100$

Thank you very much for your involvement.

Comment: What's the database engine?

Comment: I've added some sample data as a picture. It's pretty straight forward. For example third line should be 39.5877 * 58 * 12. The amount of comma's can vary up to 5 for my full dataset. I'm a beginner, we are using SQL Server Management Studio if that helps.

Comment: You didn't explain what "P" means.

Comment: Sorry, P = B. It was a mistake in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, it uses `STRING_SPLIT()` to split the discount string into separate rows. It then takes the discount and calculates (100 - Discount) /100. The Log() of these values are taken and aggregated using `SUM()` and `Group By` on the basis that a * b is the equivalent EXP(LOG(a) + LOG(b)).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/985462/19)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE FactTurnover
(
  ID INT,
  SalesPriceExcl NUMERIC (9,4),
  Discount VARCHAR(100)
  )

 INSERT INTO FactTurnover
 VALUES 

   (1, 100, '10'),
   (2, 39.5877, '58, 12'),
   (3, 100, '50, 10, 15'),
   (4, 100, 'B')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Id, SalesPriceExcl, 
         CASE WHEN value = 'B' THEN 0
         ELSE CAST(value as int) END AS Discount
  From FactTurnover
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Discount, ',')
)
SELECT Id,  
       Min(SalesPriceExcl) AS SalesPriceExcludingDiscount,
       EXP(SUM(LOG((100 - Discount) / 100.0))) As TotalDiscount,
       Cast(EXP(SUM(LOG((100 - Discount) / 100.0))) * 
            MIN(SalesPriceExcl) As Numeric(9,2))
        PriceAfterDiscount
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/985462/19/0)**:

```
| Id | SalesPriceExcludingDiscount |       TotalDiscount | PriceAfterDiscount |
|----|-----------------------------|---------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |                         100 |                 0.9 |                 90 |
|  2 |                     39.5877 | 0.36960000000000004 |              14.63 |
|  3 |                         100 | 0.38250000000000006 |              38.25 |
|  4 |                         100 |                   1 |                100 |
```

Comment: Hi Steve, seems to work great indeed!
I'm now trying to incorporate it into DataBricks but I'm stuck on finding the equivalent for for example cross apply string_split. Any idea? 

Thanks a bunch already!

Comment: I'm also trying to understand what the cross apply is doing or why you use it?
Thanks!

Comment: @YanniPattas you can accept this answer if it solves your SQL Server problem. I would then probably ask a new question relating to DataBricks. Cross Apply turns applies the string_Split to the column and splits them into new rows, one for each comma separated value.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a case, so case when Discount "string" then SalesPriceExcl * numbers to multiply with

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to test this for floating-point accuracy:

```
select min(SalesPriceExcl) * exp(sum(log(case 1 - cast(pct as decimal(2)) / 100))) 
from dwh.FactTurnover cross apply (
    select
        case values when 'B' then 0 when 'P' then '??' else value end as pct 
    from string_split(Discount, ',')
group by ID
```